# cut expression from specific character with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having an application where the user gives a email. For each user on directory is created on my server. I would like the name of the directory to be based on the email of the user, but I can't use directly the email. What `I would like is to modify the email to make it a appropritate directory . For example if I have: name.lastname@test.com, I wouls like to create the string namelastname. How can I do that with javascript.`

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for some string manipulation functions. Things like regular expressions might come in handy here. You might even be able to use simpler functions such as [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,  split replace and trim.

```
var email = "name.lastname@test.com";

var str = email.split("@")[0].replace(".","").trim();
```

What's actually happening here is:

1. `email.split("@")` - This will use the `@` character as a delimiter and split the entire string everywhere the `@` char appears. In this example it will yield 2 elements:
   `[ 'name.lastname', 'test.com' ]`
   *Note that the delimiter character is not returned in these results.*
2. We only need to be concerned with the text before the `@`, so we access the first element in the result: `email.split("@")[0]`
3. Now we use the `replace` function to swap specific characters. In this case we are swapping the `.` character for an empty string `""`, ie: remove it.
4. The `trim` command removes excess whitespace that might be left over.

What we are left with is the desired `namelastname` string.

References:

- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: I hope you approve of my edits, @brroshan. When dealing with users that don't have a deep knowledge in the language or are just getting started, it's always helpful to give a more detailed explanation of what exactly is happening in the commands that are used. Links to relevant documentation is also very useful.

Comment: Great edit @Lix thanks. I was about to add an explanation and references but you beat me to it.